# onSaveInstanceState in Fragment not working

Tags: java, android

I want using savedInstanceState to storage data when rotate or change view but the function not called and they don't return my data for me.

```
//Return data
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null){
       Log.d(TAG, savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("pathGalleries") + "");
    }
}

//Storage data
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putParcelableArrayList("pathGalleries", customGalleries);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Comment: show the activity code as well. is the activity also overriding the `onSaveInstanceState` ?

Comment: i using this code in the fragment @SMR

Comment: Yes, but is the activity also using `onSaveInstanceState` method?

Comment: it is preferred to store these variables in fragments arguments

Comment: make sure that inside your activitiy's `onSaveInstanceState` method you call `super.onSaveInstanceState()`